# Using insecure protocols with repositories build.gradle react native

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

I'm trying to install this library https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer after manually linking it to the project I got this error

> A problem occurred configuring project
> ':react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer:classpath'.
> > Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository
> > 'BintrayJCenter(http://jcenter.bintray.com/)' to redirect to a secure
> > protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol
> > for more details.

The issue is probably here in this file build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation project(':react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer')
    ...
    }
```

I'm aware that I should use `allowInsecureProtocol` but as I'm not familiar with Java I'm not sure how to achieve the same result as in the code below

```
maven { url "http://myorg.example/repo"; allowInsecureProtocol = true }
```

Comment: Actually, I think that the real problem is this:  `jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }`.  I think it should be `jcenter { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/" }`.

Comment: That line doesn't exist in any of the files

Comment: If it doesn't exist, how come I found it?  :-)

Comment: I wasn't looking at node_modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is this line:

```
jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
```

It is line #3 of https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer/blob/master/android/build.gradle

I think it should be:

```
jcenter { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
```

or

```
jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"; allowInsecureProtocol = true }
```

Note that Gradle (deliberately!) doesn't provide a way to turn these checks off *except* on a case-by-case basis.  The docs say:

> *"For security purposes this intentionally requires a user to opt-in to using insecure protocols on case by case basis.*
>
> *Gradle intentionally does not offer a global system/gradle property that allows a universal disable of this check."*

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the use of insecure jcentre endpoints. Consider using the system-defined endpoints which are loaded automatically.

> Instead of `jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }`
>
> > use `jcenter()`

Answer (score 0):

Update this lines

```
jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"; allowInsecureProtocol = true }

maven {url "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/"; allowInsecureProtocol = true}
```

work for me this change